# IdentityServer4 Replacing AddDeveloperSigningCredential with certifcate file

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to change from builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential() to using a self signed pfx file (the site is going in share hosting so can't add to cert store etc).

I have created the pfx file and I am sure I've had this working at somepoint using the following code in my Identity Server Project:

```
public static class SignInKeyExtension
{
    public static void AddCertificateFromFile(
        this IIdentityServerBuilder builder,
        IConfigurationSection options,
        ILogger logger, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        var webRoot = env.WebRootPath;
        var keyFileVirtualPath = options.GetValue<string>("KeyFilePath");
        var keyFilePassword = options.GetValue<string>("KeyFilePassword");
        var keyFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, keyFileVirtualPath);



        if (File.Exists(keyFile))
        {
            logger.LogDebug($"SigninCredentialExtension adding key from file {keyFile}");

            // You can simply add this line in the Startup.cs if you don't want an extension. 
            // This is neater though ;)
            builder.AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(keyFile, keyFilePassword));
        }
        else
        {
            logger.LogError($"SigninCredentialExtension cannot find key file {keyFile}");
        }
    }
}
```

The calling this extension from startup.cs ConfigureServices

```
if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }
        else
        {
           Extensions.SignInKeyExtension.AddCertificateFromFile(builder, Configuration.GetSection("SigninKeyCredentials"), _logger, Environment);
        }
```

But then when I try and log in from a separate project it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop signing in.   I haven't done anything to this project with regards this self signed cert.  In the log files from this project I get this:

2018-08-07 15:56:46.609 +01:00 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "oidc" was challenged.
2018-08-07 15:56:50.326 +01:00 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "Cookies" signed in.
2018-08-07 15:56:50.344 +01:00 [Information] "Identity.Application" was not authenticated. Failure message: "Unprotect ticket failed"

Can only tell from above Am I missing something?

Thanks
Richard